# Can't move my HTML button

Tags: html, css

Well, I just started coding HTML and I'm having problems with a button. In CSS when I try to use padding or margin it doesn't move my button. The problem is that my button is too close to my H1 and so I need to move it.

Comment: Use margin property

Comment: Try to append your HTML snippet to improve your question.

Comment: In ceases like this you should include your code. There are many possible reasons why a piece of code doesn't work, especially with CSS. By including your code, you help us help you.

Comment: set `margin-top:XXpx`

Answer (score 0):

1- Make sure you've linked the style sheet well,

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="Relative path to style sheet" />`

2- Make sure that the syntax you have used is free of errors,

Use this validator until you have fewer errors:

[For HTML file.](https://validator.w3.org/)

[For CSS file.](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

3- Do not give up.

```css
button {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<button>Click me</button>
```